# Avada theme, changing related project text

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

Hi I have been trying to change 1 word of text within the Avada theme.

Here is the line of text: http://prntscr.com/ibac1t

This is on all gallery pages, but here is one page for example: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/nursteadcourt/our-destination/wedding-5/?portfolioCats=24%2C21%2C23%2C22

I can't seem to find where it is to change, I would like to change the word 'Projects' to either: Pictures or Gallery's. This is probably more complex than I think it will be.

Any assistance in this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Is this type of thing hard to change? Or is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the file located at

*/website_folder/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avada-functions.php*.

It is in the "*avada_render_related_posts*" function and at/around line 327.

Copy the file to your child theme folder or else you will have to update this file after every theme update.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We use something similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery('.related-posts > div > h3').html('Posts Relacionados');
/*]]>*/
});
</script>
```